# How to configure the pop3 protocol in silverlight to receive email

Tags: silverlight

I need to receive the email in Silverlight page using pop3 client protocol or is there any other way to do that

Guide me pls!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "receive" an email you need a pop3 server. The silverlight application runs in the client and it not possible to make a server on the client with silverlight. What you can do is create a pop3 server on the machine serving the silverlight page in c# :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20609/POP3-Server

and communicate with this server using WCF.